# How to attach an object to a deforming object

Tags: modifiers, parent

[image]

[image]

I made a blue object that bends left and right using subdivision modifiers and simple deform modifiers.

I set parent the red cone to the blue object.

But when I defoamed the blue object, the red cone is still there.

[image]

I want the red cone to move along the blue object without changing its shape when I bend the blue object.

I want to know how to attach object to a bending object properly.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the cone, shift select the bar, switch to *Edit* mode, select 3 vertices of the top face and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Make Vertex Parent*:

[image]

[image]